# Skip over code snippets in post excerpts

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The preview of questions (on the main pages) displays a short text, which is the beginning of the question. However, questions in some keywords are often phrased as

> Hi, I have a data set which looks like (some data here). Why does it bar?

or

> Consider a code as (some code here). I want to do foo

These look bad on the front page, as code or data is not displayed properly:

[Real-life example #1:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388944/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-the-number-of-non-null-columns)

> I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this: col1 col2 col3 col4 0 NaN D NaN I 1 NaN NaN F J 2 NaN NaN NaN NaN 3 A E NaN ...

or

[Real-life example: #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376772/lookup-value-in-column-based-on-table)

> I have this table: I C H O P S T C D E M V W R 4.76 04 08 04 05 04 04 08 5.56 05 09 05 06 05 05 09 03 6.35 03 02 04 ...

. My suggestion would be to ignore these snippets in the length. The display on the front pages would rather be to *skip* stuff in quotes, do not count them towards the string length and rather add stuff that follows afterwards to the preview text:

> I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:  [...]. I'm looking to keep the rows where there are at-least two non null entries:[...]. It's really easy to select all non-null columns using boolean indexing, but how would you generalize it to keep rows with >= x number of non-null entries?

and

> I have this table: [...]. Given these two inputs: - a letter corresponding to one of the other headers (H O P S T C D E M V W R) and -a number which is in the column with that header, I want to lookup the value in column I C which is on the same row as that number.

(With literal dots or similar to display a placeholder)

Comment: I thought this question was going to be about users who paste their code into a question and never check the preview to make sure it actually appears.

Comment: Only code blocks should be ignored. `inline snippets` usually are a significant part of the sentence; and they help to clarify which syntactic constructs the question is about. Not sure what you mean by "*skip stuff in quotes*"?

Comment: What about the users who spends their time formatting indentation in code?...

Comment: That's the crux: Indentation is removed in preview texts. @Bergi: Yeah, I suppose we can apply this to code blocks only.

Comment: @Bergi why hate `code::blocks`? ;) (*I agree with you*)